# C# issue adding static member to list

Tags: c#, list, static

I'm trying to add some objects in a listbox (throw a binding list), but when i'm displaying the list, the static member of the class has always the same display, the last value. There is no problem in my list or class for the other properties.

In my form:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         shape.gsPtAcc = ptdep;

         if (shape is Segment)
         {
             seg = shape as Segment;
             seg.gsScPtAcc = ptarr;
         }

         shape.incremNumber();
         Console.WriteLine(shape.Number);//write the correct value
         shapeList.Add(shape);
         listBox1.DataSource = null;
         listBox1.DataSource = shapeList;
        }
    }
```

In my mother class, shape:

```
namespace MyGraphicComponents
{
    abstract class Shape: IComparable<Shape>, IDrawable, INotifyPropertyChanged, IIsPointIn
    {
        protected MyPoint ptAcc;
        public MyPoint gsPtAcc
        {
            get { return ptAcc; }
            set { ptAcc = value; }
        }

        protected static int compt = 0;

        public int Number
        {
            get { return compt; }
            set { compt = value; }
        }
        public int incremNumber ()
        {
            return ++compt;
        }
    }
}
```

So the result, when i'm adding shape will be:

- In the console:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
- But in the listbox:
  5
  5
  5
  5
  5

Answer (score 2):

A static member of a class will have the same value in all instances  of this class classes

read more here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/98f28cdx.aspx

replace

```
  protected static int compt = 0;
```

with

```
protected int compt = 0;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I solved it by Using number as a property, and by this way, I have been able to keep the static propertie, just have to do `Number=incremNumber ();`

Comment: @RemiHirtz why do you need this static property its seems like a mise use of static

Comment: It's for school, I don't have the choice :s